# Angular Visual Code Terminal Error Command Executed and Failed Exit Code 1

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I just updated my local Angular Cli version to 15.2.5 and any time I try to run ng build or ng serve I get Command Executed and Failed (Exit Code 1).  I've never run into this before and a Google search didn't turn up much and I'm completely stumped.  I've restarted my machine and Visual Code but still the error shows up.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.